# android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I know it's old question, but I don't find the solution for issue
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed.

Here is my code:

```
public synchronized String getType(String suffix) {
    String basicSuffix = suffix.toLowerCase();
    String countQuery = SQL_SELECT_ALL + TABLE_TYPE + SQL_WHERE + KEY_TYPE_SUFFIX + " =? ";
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String type = "";
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, new String[]{basicSuffix});
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.getString(1) != null) {
                type = cursor.getString(1);
            } else {
                type = FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
            }

        } else {
            type = FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return type;
}
```

Log informs that error occurred in line code `cursor.movetoFirst();`

Thank you.

Comment: Does the message go on to say how many open cursors there are? e.g. `"Cursor window allocation of 2048kb failed.# open Cursors=736 (#cursors opendby this proc=736)".`

Comment: The message is "Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=2 (# cursors opened by this proc=2)"

Comment: See if you get the same for these alternatives: a) removing the space before =? (i.e `KEY_TYPE_SUFFIX + "=? "`) or b) try `cursor = db.query(TABLE_TYPE,null,KEY_TYPE_SUFFIX + "=?,new String[]{basicSuffix},null,null,null,null);` instead of `cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, new String[]{basicSuffix});`. Perhaps also try (if there's more than 2 columns) just getting the first two columns as opposed to all columns. Also see if you can find in there is another open cursor, whcih can be closed.